# "Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'" on Windows

Tags: sqlite, npm

I'm trying to install [Gekko](https://gekko.wizb.it/docs/installation/installing_gekko_on_windows.html) and I get the following error:

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.13 and node@6.9.4 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean )

C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build "--module=C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" --module_name=node_sqlite3 "--module_path=C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64" )  else (node "" configure --fallback-to-build "--module=C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" --module_name=node_sqlite3 "--module_path=C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64" )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\SOBER CHECK\\Downloads\\gekko-develop\\gekko-develop\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v48-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\SOBER CHECK\\Downloads\\gekko-develop\\gekko-develop\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v48-win32-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\SOBER CHECK\\Downloads\\gekko-develop\\gekko-develop\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.38
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sqlite3"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.13 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs sqlite3
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SOBER CHECK\Downloads\gekko-develop\gekko-develop\npm-debug.log
```

I'm on Windows 10 with Node version 6.9.4 and NPM version 3.10.10.

Please help - what can I do to resolve this and finish installing Gekko?
I've also posted this question [as an issue](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/972) on the Github repo, but I don't have much hope of a reply from there.

Any help to make this example more minimal (as in minimum verifiable example) or about any extra information required would be much appreciated; I don't know enough about this to ask an easily-answerable question.

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet?

Comment: @My3 - nope, still haven't :(

Answer (score 3):

installing `sqlite 4.0.1` instead of `3.1.13` fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Your linked GitHub issue [was resolved](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/972#issuecomment-399694596) with the solution of updating to `sqlite3@^4.0.1`.  However, the commenters on your issue are using later versions of Node v9 or later Node v10 so this `sqlite3` version upgrade may not fix your issue.  Gekko updated to `sqlite3` v4.0.2 in Gekko v0.6.3 so upgrade to that version or above, reinstall and then you'll be using the latest version of `sqlite3` at the time of writing which contains the resolution for your issue.

All that said, looking at your error message, it appears that you don't have `python` available on your PATH:

```
Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

So try both approaches - upgrade Gekko and ensure Python is installed and available within your environment.