# Error installing 'npm i' for node-red server in node.js

Tags: node-modules, node-red

I'm trying to use netbeast in my node-red server, and I am unable to install 'npm i' which is required for IoT. How can I install that in correct way?

I have tried some step by step process using "https://opensource.com/life/16/5/netbeast", but I'm getting some unidentified errors

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v64-win32-x64.tar.gz

node-pre-gyp 
ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.13 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

node-pre-gyp 
ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v64-win32-x64.tar.gz

node-pre-gyp 
ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.13 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.13 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script.

I'm getting these type of errors and even I have tried with install 'sqllite3' modules individually but I'm getting the same errors. I have went through with

'https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/758',

'["Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993141/failed-at-the-sqlite33-1-13-install-script-node-pre-gyp-install-fallback-to)',

'[Error installing sqlite3 in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461439/error-installing-sqlite3-in-node-js)'

even I have tried with so many else but still same problem

Comment: The errors you have listed are not fatal, they just mean that there is not a pre-built version of the binary component required for the node. Please edit the question to 1) format the errors using the toolbar to make them easier to read 2)  include the entries after those in the log which should show npm trying to build the binary components.

Comment: I'm very new to node.js, so will you please guide me how to start "net beast" local server and what are the components need to install for running the server properly